# Number Parser program: why strtol/strtod fails for exponential and hex numbers

Tags: c, linux

I have written a small code, which breaks any string (exported as environment variable) into it's whole number and fractional part.

Example:
    export ENV_NUM=3.45

The program will print:
      whole number: 3 Fractional: 0.45

Additionally this program also scans if the exported number is out-of-range or invalid number in which case, it exits printing an error message.

**To simplify things for reader let me explain the logic i have used**:
     I have scanned the number and the number is broken into 2 parts using `strtok` whereever it finds a decimal (.), and then assigns the first token to integral part and the next token to fractional part.

**Problem faced**:
Now the problem with this program is: it gives erroneous results if the exported number is a hex number or an exponential number.

Can you let me know what is the problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


static  time_t       wholeNumber;  
static  float        fractional; 

void numberParser(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 numberParser( ); 
 printf("Whole number: %12d, Fractional: %5.8f\n", wholeNumber, fractional);
 return 0;
}

void numberParser( void )
 {
     char * charPtr, * numberFormatErr;
     charPtr = getenv("ENV_NUM"); 

     if ( charPtr == NULL )
            return;

     double envVal = strtod(charPtr, &numberFormatErr);

     /* This part checks if the string is a valid number and not negative */

     if ( (numberFormatErr == charPtr) || (*numberFormatErr != '\0') ) {
            printf("exited: ENV_NUM is not a number\n");
            exit(1);
     }
     else if ( envVal < 0 ) {
            printf("exited: ENV_NUM a negative number\n");
            exit(1);
     }

     /* This part breaks the string into integral and float part */

     char * tokens = strtok(charPtr, ".");
     int count = 0;
errno = 0;

     while ( tokens != NULL ) {
    //printf("Token scanned: %s\n",tokens);
            long d = strtol(tokens, NULL, 10);
    //printf("token to long: %5d\n",d);

            if ( errno == ERANGE && d == LONG_MAX ) {
                   printf("exited: ENV_NUM not in valid range.");
                   exit(1);
            }

            if ( count == 0 ) {
                    ( wholeNumber = d );
            }

            tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    count++;
       }
            fractional = (envVal) - (double)(wholeNumber);
   }
```

Here is the output:

```
Correct output for normal numbers
[time_related]$ ./a.out 
Whole number:    3, Fractional: 0.56000000
```

Wrong output for hex:
    [time_related]$ export ENV_NUM=0x21

```
[time_related]$ ./a.out 
Whole number:  0, Fractional: 33.00000000 (should be 33, 0)
```

Wrong output for exponential:
    [time_related]$ export ENV_NUM=3e3

```
[time_related]$ ./a.out 
Whole number:            3, Fractional: 2997.00000000 (should be 3000, 0)
```

Comment: All you look for is a decimal point. Those non-decimal numbers don't have a decimal point.

Comment: @Dave Newton: 0x21 = (16^2) + (16^0) = 33. But why the fractional part is coming as 33?

Comment: @Dave Newton: No you are mistaken, if you export only 3, it gives `Whole Number = 3`, `fractional = 0.0000` The program correctly handles only whole numbers exported without decimal point.

Comment: See my updated comment; I misread your output. Bottom line is that you're trying to tokenize based on a decimal point when not all your input even *has* a decimal point. That will lead you to the answer.

Comment: @Dave Newton: You mean, if i export only 5, it will give a wrong answer?? No you are mistaken, it correctly handles. Sorry but i already told the same thing once in the above comment.

Comment: How many decimal points are in `3e3` or `0x21`? Sorry but I already told the same thing twice in the above comments.

Comment: @Dave Newton: I am sorry but not understanding the point you are trying to emphasize. In that case as you say why the `export ENV_NUM=3` works? This should also fail right?

Comment: No. Trace your code when there's no decimal point in the input for hex and exponential numbers.

Comment: @Dave Newton: I exported `0x21.1` hoping to get the output 33.0625. It still gives whole number as 0 fractional as 33.0625

Comment: Can you *please* trace your code where there's *no* decimal point in the input for hex and exponential numbers first? What do you think `strtok` will give for the tokens for "0x21"? Is it null? What happens if it isn't null?

Comment: @Dave Newton i am doing `fractional = (envVal) - (double)(wholeNumber);` So wholeNumber is 0, which means strtol fails here. and envVal is the original number.

Comment: Good luck; please refer to @PhiLho's answer for more hints.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 You are assuming strtol can parse hexadecimal numbers. It cannot when you give it a base of 10. `strtol(tokens, NULL, 10);` Right there you tell it to look for a base 10 (decimal) number.0x21 is not a decimal number, but the first 0 is. strtol() will interpret hex if you give it a base 16. In the case of base 16, strtol will accept a prefix of "0x". If you give it a base 0, it will try to figure out what you want: i.e. with base 0, if you feed it "0x21" it will interpret it as hex. if you feed it 21, it will interpret it as decimal. `strtod`  does understand the 0x prefix though

Comment: @nos: Ahh that was really a great one, i will use "0" with strtol, how about exponential numbers? Where can i get to tell strtol to parse exponential numbers as well?

Comment: @kingsmasher you cannot.

Comment: @nos: So there is no way?? What should i do if the user enters an expo?? This number needs to be fed to a timespec structure which takes only `long`? Is there any other way out that i can accept and scan exponential numbers?

Comment: @nos: If not strtol any other API which scans and parses an expo? Later i can typecast it to long.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 There's many options: 1. Tell the user he cannot enter exonents. 2. use strtod to parse the input, and extract the fraction from the double/float it gives you. 3. Read the input and parse it the text yourself 4. etc. This is a completely different question though, so ask another question about how you should parse your input.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that strtod parses hex numbers, as I looked at two references and they don't mention such capability, but why not.
Note that 0x21 = 33, not 35.

You made intermediary print, use it: for 0x21, envVal is 33, strtol fails to parse beyond the x, so it returns 0, and fractional is envVal - 0 = 33
Idem for 3e3: it isn't an long number, so strtol returns 3, and fractional is 3000-3

You should add a check on the result of strtol, like you did for strtod...

Comment: Yes, it's 33. I have correct it sometimes back (need to refresh your page). But in that case, how do i handle if the user enters a hex number or an exponential? Can you give the reference where it says strtod won't parse hex or exponential?

Comment: It *will* parse those. PLEASE take a pencil and paper and trace your code for a hex and exponential input, *without* a decimal point.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Sorry Dave, but it fails to parse. strtol fails to parse the first token and hence it is 0, and hence fractional part becomes the integral part. `fractional = (envVal) - (double)(wholeNumber);` envVal=0x21, and wholeNumber=0 (fails to parse).

Comment: Philho, you mean how do we handle if user enters a hex or an expo?

Comment: You said to give the reference where it says strtod won't parse hex or exponential; I said it will parse those. I didn't say anything about strtol; PhiLho did. (And strtol will parse hex if given a base.)

Comment: @Dave Newton: strtol fails to parse hex and expo, that is for 200% sure, i just tried it with a test program, doing `getenv` on a `hex` and `exp` and then parsing it using `strtol`

Comment: @kingsmasher strtol is not the same as strtod . strtod *will* handle hex numbers prefixed with "0x". strtol(tokens, NULL, 10) *will not*. With a base 10, strtol will parse the first 0 in "0x21", which is ... 0.

Comment: @kinsmasher, strtod != strtol. And strol with base 16 will parse hex. But I give up.

Comment: @Dave Newton: I never said that, strtod=strtol. Did I? I have put a check point at strtod, if it would have failed, it would have exited from there itself. Anyways, as suggested i am using 0 in strtol as it will take care for all, dec and hex. But i don't know what to do with exponential numbers.

Comment: You said "can you give the ref where it says strtod won't parse hex..." I said "It *will* parse those." You said "It fails to parse. strtol..." I said "I didn't say anything about strtol." You said "strtol fails to parse hex, 200% sure". I said "ur doing it wrong".

Comment: "_Can you give the reference where it says strtod won't parse hex or exponential?_" I haven't said that, I said that strtol won't parse them. "_how do we handle if user enters a hex or an expo?_" As said, check the result of strtol, like you did for strtod. Change the logic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double numberParser(char *str){
    double val;
    long  lval;
    char *p;

    val=strtod(str, &p);//exponential number OK!, 0x prefix from C99
    if(*p == '\0')
        return val;
    else if(str[0] == '0' && (str[1] == 'x' || str[1] == 'X')){
        lval = strtol(str, &p, 16);//strtol(str, &p, 0) better
        if(*p == '\0')
            return (double)lval;
    }
    return -1.0;//error
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    double wk;
    int i;

    i= wk = numberParser("3.45");
    printf("Whole number: %12d, Fractional: %5.8f\n", i, wk - i); 

    i= wk = numberParser("0x21");
    printf("Whole number: %12d, Fractional: %5.8f\n", i, wk - i); 

    i= wk = numberParser("3e3");
    printf("Whole number: %12d, Fractional: %5.8f\n", i, wk - i); 

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Whole number:            3, Fractional: 0.45000000
Whole number:           33, Fractional: 0.00000000
Whole number:         3000, Fractional: 0.00000000
```

Comment: There is an easier way, just by using 0 in strtol, as the base, as nos suggested, but this code won't take care for exponential numbers.